# Is there any way to trick WP7 to use Data connection as Wi-fi(larger marketplace downloads)?

Tags: wifi, 3g

What I would like to do, is make my WP7 device see my Data Connection as a Wi-Fi connection to download larger apps from the Marketplace when I am away from home or away from a wi-fi connection. Something that could be turned on and off.

Is this even possible?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The cap has been set to 20 MB and forces wifi for every download larger than that. There is no way to override this behavior.

Most 3g or cellular dataconnections are also not very stable for large downloads so I think this is one of the reasons why Microsoft didn't allow you to do this. Failing a large download a couple of times and retrying it can cost you a lot of data used through your 3g connection.

That plus of course mobile operators don't want people to download that much through their cellular connection so I guess Microsoft is doing them a favor by disabling this.

Comment: I've downloaded large files over 2G (Yes, EDGE) on a Droid. Most of those applications allow you to resume the download if for any reason the connection was cut off. 

I don't know about the last paragraph. Doesn't hold true for me. I mean, people might want to download an app when they're on road where WiFi is common. It should've been like a warning sign popping up if we were to use the mobile data download and suggesting to turn the WiFi on. Ofcourse, we could choose to ignore it altogether.